# How to connect with database in talend

Tags: database, ms-access, talend

I am facing a problem while connecting to my Access Database. I have selected the Database but when I checked the connection, an error message appear. The error message is 
: [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Ressources système insuffisantes (in English: [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Insufficient system resources).

Please give me proper solution.

Comment: Are you using the tAccessConnection or the tAccessInput component? Make sure the DB version is correct (2003 or 2007). Try creating a new Access file and connecting to that and see if you get the same error or if everything's working.

Comment: have you confirmed that your odbc connection is working well?

Comment: One could also be that there is a 2GB limit for the size of the temporary files generated by the ODBC Access driver.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for this fuzzy error message is the usage of mixed architectures which seems to be a familiar connection problem between MS Access and Talend.
Try to avoid mixed architectures and either use 32bit or 64bit programs for Office, Java, Talend and the ODBC driver.
The latter is somewhat confusing in Windows 64bit:

- The odbcad32.exe in the %WINDIR%\SysWOW64 folder is for 32bit
- The ODBC tool found in the Control Panel is for 64bit

Therefore, make sure that you setup the right data source at the right location.

One more thing: make sure that you select the latest MS Access ODBC driver when creating the datasource. If you add a new DS in the ODBC tool, you should usually see two versions, an old one shipped with Windows (6.0) and a new one shipped with your Office installation (14.0 for Office 2010).